# Architectural / Design question related to C# project, Azure and Office SharePoint 365

Tags: c#, azure, office365, sharepoint-online

Need feedback and input. Here's a scenario. End goal is to update a custom list in Office 365 SharePoint site using data from external site. Note that SharePoint is not on-premise.

1. End-users fills out a form online at a 3rd party web site
   -- *Assume that your org does not want to drop this 3rd party web site for any reason*
2. Form data is posted to an internal database
   -- *Assume DB is inaccessible from 3rd party site except via web form grid view and managed exports via CSV*
3. Web Hook endpoint is configured to also send form data to receiver on MS Azure
4. Azure endpoint "receiver" gets and stores form data in Azure storage account queue

That's the first phase. How would you "feel" about the second phase being this scenario?

1. A web service coded in C# installed on a local server that periodically wakes up
   -- *Yes, I know that you can also store a C# developed service on Azure cloud. But let's assume that you are a frugal penny savings minded accountant in a previous life.*
   -- *Yes, I'm also aware that a local service approach short-circuits the entire online path that the form data would otherwise take. But let's assume that at least one other person in the team agrees that locally, we have much more control with what we can do with the data, assuming that it's final destination as a new item a SharePoint list is just the tip of the iceberg.*
2. Connects to Azure online storage
3. Downloads all queue items for processing
4. Saves queue items as new items in Office 365 SharePoint List
5. Dequeue items in Azure queue

Note: In this scenario, we're not taking advantage of Azure Queue Trigger which would require the second phase of the project code to reside in Azure also. Either as a Azure function or function app. Whichever the correct nomenclature is. The strategy for this approach is to save time from having to go through all the steps for coding authentication (OAuth or otherwise) to access the Office 365 SharePoint List. Lots of steps here and various choices for which SharePoint access methodology to use, i.e. REST, CSOM, etc.

Note2: A local service app in customer domain using local domain credentials (credential also added to Office 365 SharePoint site) will have trusted access to SharePoint list so there's no need to configure AD nor configure any certificates just for adding a new item to a SharePoint list.

-- Assume you already have some C# plumbing for Queue Trigger and that you can successfully read items in the queue. The only missing piece at this point is sending the data to Office 365 SharePoint online.

So, Yay or Nay? To help with understanding, what are the flaws in the second phase thinking/strategy and how would it negatively impact you if you were a developer having to maintain this solution in the event I am abducted by outer space aliens or fall into a very deep sinkhole that winds up somewhere on the other side of the planet, after the solution goes into production? Would you lay flowers on my cemetery headstone or spray paint graffiti on it?

What would you prefer, if any, to see as the second phase of the solution (that's all after storing form data into Azure Storage Queue?) (Keep in mind the monthly costs of Azure).

Comment: I won't comment on the architecture as a whole- it does sound like you've thought through it pretty thoroughly. However, I did want to mention that while deploying a Function app locally is possible (the host is open source) for supportability something you could look at is using the WebJobs SDK outside of a Function app. Webjobs are essentially just console apps and in previous roles I have successfully deployed them locally as Windows services while still taking advantage of things like queue triggers.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for the information. Looking into the WebJobs SDK ASAP.

Comment: The developer mindset in me likes the idea of an Azure Function, it can also run functions on a timer, and furthermore costs would be next to nothing when run on a consumption plan (literally pennies). Cost here is getting ramped up on authentication like you said, if your team has not worked on that before it can be a challenge. What about Logic Apps? I believe that would be a no code/integrated auth flow approach, and also cost effective